# Python Flask multiple POST request

Tags: python, flask

Flask code below gets multiple requests (currently 22) from an Android device which gathers local information (all different size payload) and sends it simultaneously.

When Flask receives it, it creates 22 files with same data (probably the once it receives first)

```
from flask import Flask, request
from multiprocessing import Pool
import json, copy, random
from time import time, sleep 

pool = ""
app = Flask(__name__)

def writeToFile(callingFrom, content):
    # seconds = int(time())
    seconds = random.randint(1,999999999)
    fp = open(callingFrom + "_" + str(seconds) + ".txt", "w")
    json.dump(content, fp)
    fp.close()

@app.route('/recieve_file.php', methods=['POST'])
def recieve_file():
    pool.apply_async(writeToFile,['FILE', request.form])
    return json.dumps("ecieve_file")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=30)
    app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Each request should create file with its own payload

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why can't you just receive all the files in the same request, seeing as the files are just plaintext?

Comment: I don't have access to Android project that is sending the data

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't close the file, but it doesn't matter in your problem. The problem is that you have a lot of requests in one time and when python creates files they have same names. You can try to use random instead of time and you will see that every thing works.

Comment: closing file or using random values doesn't work. This code creates 22 files but with same payload data.